# Get environment variable value of the base system in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How to get environment variable value of the base system in the Dockerfile

```
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VAR=${NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VAR}
```

Comment: What's the more specific issue you're running into; where should the variable come from?  Have you tried passing it in as a Dockerfile `ARG`?  What happens if you run the image in an environment where that variable has a different value?

Comment: i don't have access to change the build commande i want the docker to take the env vars of the system (ubuntu) where we run the container

Comment: A specific goal of Docker is to isolate the application from changes in the host like this.  You need to use a `docker run -e` option to pass the environment variable into the container at run time, or run the program without Docker.